# Why has the web browser reversed my menu options?

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a main menu, and in the HTML code, it is in the correct order, but when viewed in the browser, it is reversed. Why?

HTML:

```
  <div class="header">
    <img src="images/JTS_1_B_FL31.png" alt="J.T.S Logo" class="logo" />
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="current"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="support.php">Support</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="myaccount/">My Account</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;

  background-color: #1D242D;
}
.logo{
  padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
  float: left;
  }
.menu{
  float: right:
}
li{
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px 5px 7px 5px;

}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What browser/version are you seeing the behavior in? And just to clarify, you expect to see, Home, Services, Support, Contact , My Account, but you see this reversed correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the LI's floated: right, as well as the #menu floated right, which will layout from right to left. You might try float: left on them, maybe try without a float attribute on either #menu and the LI.

Comment: I removed the float:right from the LI'S but then the whole menu floats to the left of the window. And yeah, I know, but I've never had this problem before. Everything just seems to be f*****g up right now, and I'm not doing anything differently. (other then floating the li's right, i did that just to see why the hell it wouldn't float to the right with just the menu one)

Comment: @Lucifer - If you could provide a link to your page, that would help. Since you are floating all LI's on the page with your code, my guess is you're doing some other things wrong, too. Btw, you should not apply a style to any element type for any specific issue such as this. Use classes and CSS selectors instead (such as `#menu li` maybe).

Comment: @Lucifer, I've put together a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6fM6E/) for my own answer, which seems to coincide with @Jared's. See if that's what you want.

Comment: We all have those days (er, nights). :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use CSS to float things right, they are attached to the right of the page in the order that you list them.

In this case, 'Home' is getting attached to the right of the page, then 'Services' is attached as far right as possible (which ends up being to the left of 'Home').

You either need to reverse the order of your list (since this is expected behaviour), or possibly put the entire list in a single div which is floated right.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've told the list-elements to `float: right`. They're doing exactly what you told them to. If you leave the `li` elements with `display: inline` and remove the `float` declaration they should appear in the right order, with the menu itself still floated to the right.

Seems to work (please note the colour change of the `a` elements, blue-on-black was painful to try and read): [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6fM6E/).

Answer (score 0):

You are floating each list item `<li>`. This causes each new list item to appear to the left of the previously floated items.

Answer (score 0):

float: right within the same box element will put elements added later to the left of a previously right-floated element. if you don't like Jared's suggestion, you can add them in reverse order.